# How to make point in polygon in geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have two pandas dataframe with geopandas array

first one, `pnts`

```
0         POINT (96.69866 5.20478)
1         POINT (97.92708 2.34781)
2         POINT (96.12920 4.13244)
3         POINT (96.85947 4.71685)
4         POINT (97.95656 4.47959)
                   ...            
2922    POINT (136.06094 -1.17746)
2923    POINT (140.70931 -2.56853)
2924    POINT (138.31903 -2.37457)
2925    POINT (140.62557 -4.90224)
2926    POINT (136.07973 -1.15792)
Name: geometry, Length: 2927, dtype: geometry
```

second one, `polys`

```
0        POLYGON ((104.82248 -2.98102, 104.82165 -2.985...
1        POLYGON ((104.75516 -3.01316, 104.75480 -3.013...
2        POLYGON ((104.77081 -2.98185, 104.77082 -2.981...
3        POLYGON ((104.77081 -2.98185, 104.77070 -2.981...
4        POLYGON ((104.77317 -2.99340, 104.77316 -2.993...
                               ...                        
81907    POLYGON ((138.79489 -4.09306, 138.78723 -4.096...
81908    POLYGON ((136.88606 -3.76603, 136.86576 -3.772...
81909    POLYGON ((121.51784 -8.76968, 121.51784 -8.769...
81910    POLYGON ((122.69762 0.87165, 122.69698 0.87106...
81911    POLYGON ((97.48882 1.09282, 97.48853 1.09108, ...
Name: geometry, Length: 81912, dtype: geometry
```

What I want to do is, to know which polygon `gdf['geometry']` include

what I did is

```
pnts = pnts.assign(**{key: pnts.within(geom) for key, geom in polys.items()})
```

And the error

```
<ipython-input-39-aaf67bdae48e> in <module>
----> 3 pnts = pnts.assign(**{key: pnts.within(geom) for key, geom in polys.items()})

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really simplifies to an `sjoin()`.  Example below shows which cities (pnts) are in which countries (polys)

```
import geopandas as gpd

pnts = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
polys = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

pnts.sjoin(polys)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'sjoin' ` after I try this

Comment: make sure you are using geopandas 0.10.0 +

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas=0.10` and `bash: condaL command not found ...`

Comment: depends on how you have your environment configured.  I use virtual envs and pip, so `pip install geopandas --upgrade`